# How to add UIView below double status bar

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller

I want to add programmatically a red rect just on top of visible part in my ViewController. My code  is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, rect.size.width, 200);
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
}
```

When I launch it in Simulator for iPhone5, it works as expected:

[image]

Height of red rect is 400 pix = 200 * 2.

But when I toggle in-call status bar in Simulator, and launch my app again, it looks as follows:

[image]

and height of green bar is 80, as expected (= 20 * 2 * 2), but height of red rect is 360, not 400!. So the top 40 pixels of the red rect are hidden behind the green bar. How can I avoid it and to have my red rect just below green bar?

Additional info: my app is created as File->New->Project->IOS Single View Application. I have switched off "Use Autolayout" and "Use Size Classes" checkboxes.

Comment: Answer posted, but I'm a little concerned that you have disabled Autolayout for your project. It is almost necessary nowadays if you want to support more than a single screen size/orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 7, the status bar no longer affects the size/layout of your app automatically. Your red UIView is still 400px high; 40 of the pixels are being hidden behind the in-call status bar. If you want your UI elements to respect changes in the status bar height/presence, you must do so programmatically.

You can implement `application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:` and/or `application:didChangeStatusBarFrame` in your app delegate to solve this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
    ViewController *viewController = /* reference to your view controller */;
    UIView *newView = ((UIView *)(viewController.view.subviews.firstObject)); // you should really make newView a property in ViewController so you can access it properly
    newView.frame = CGRectMake(newView.frame.origin.x, newView.frame.origin.y + CGRectGetMaxY(newStatusBarFrame), newView.frame.size.width, newView.frame.size.height);
}
```